# How to change all similar rows in PSQL if one value is changed?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have a table like this:

| name | email | domain | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| contact 1 | email | website.com | null |
| contact 2 | email | website.com | null |
| contact 3 | email | website2.com | null |

The first two contacts are from the same domain.

When I change `rank` to "ignore" (it's a varchar) for contact 1, I want contact 2, which is from the same domain, to also change to ignore.

How do I accomplish that?

I started playing with PSQL triggers, but I cannot figure out how to do:

```
if column rank changes to 'ignore'
find all other rows with similar domain
then do xyz
```

Comment: You should normalize your data model. `domain` should be a foreign key to a different table. Then you only have one row per domain and you only need to change one row.

Comment: Okay so let's say that is the case, the table is normalized with another table. 

I'd still need to trigger ignore on the domain if I type 'ignore' in rank - right? Because `rank` might be anything too. But I only want to trigger ignore at domain level with when `ignore` is inserted.

Comment: Well, if it's normalized you only need to update a single row. And then automatically every row referencing that domain would use the "ignore" thing when joined against the "domain table". I don't why you would need a trigger as you only update one row.

Comment: I get you. The missing piece was the joining. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question about the trigger, but I think the better solution is to normalize your data model:

```
create table domain
(
  id integer primary key, 
  name text not null,
  rank text
);

create table the_table
(
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null, 
  email text not null,
  domain_id integer not null references domain
);
```

You can create a view that shows the domain information as in your current design:

```
create view table_and_domain
as
select t.name, 
       t.email,
       d.name as domain,
       d.rank
from the_table t
  join domain d on t.domain_id = d.id;
```

As soon as you update the `domain` table, all rows in the view `table_and_domain` will reflect the new rank.